# Combining current date code with stored procedure ti use in PowerBi

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerquery

To get the required table I have to input the value "201801" into the stored procedure query. I want to place the following code:

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(6), GETDATE(), 112)
```

In the following Sp:

```
USE [MDAmanager]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sqSupplierBalances]
    @Period = 201801,
    @SupplierString = 'select SupplierID from Suppliers ',
    @SelectionString = 'select * from vSupplierBalances order by  
     ControlOfficeName, PortfolioName, OwnerEntityName, RegionName, 
     PropertyName, PropertyManagerName, Custom1Name, Custom2Name, 
     ServiceTypeDescription, AnalysisCode, SupplierName',
    @WithCommitments = NULL,
    @UserID = NULL,
    @ExcludeInDispute = NULL,
    @IncludeSupplierPropertyReference = NULL

    SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

    GO
```

Is it possible to assign a value to the first code example and replace the "201801" in the second code example with that variable. I have been trying this but not getting it right.

Update: So I realize M query functions and SQL server functions are different. I don't how to go about answering my own question but I figured I'd give the answer here anyway.

I replaced the initial date code with:

```
 Perdiod0 = (Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()) * 100) + 
 Date.Month(DateTime.LocalNow())
```

And then just replaced the 201801 with:

```
'" & Text.From(Period0) &  "'
```

Seems to work now